# How to get the geolocation of video chosed through uiimagepickercontroller

Tags: ios, swift, xcode7, uiimagepickercontroller, phasset

I am trying to get the geolocation of the image and video though `PHAssets`, image location is being fetched through.

```
PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([imageUrl], options: opts).
```

> When i used the same below code for video this returned zero.

```
PHAsset.fetchAssetsWithALAssetURLs([videoUrl], options: opts)
```

Comment: user `let videoData = try NSData(contentsOfURL: videoDataURL, options: .DataReadingMappedIfSafe)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is tested on iOS 8 and works for videos so it should work similarly for photos with a few tweaks.

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    NSURL *videoUrl = (NSURL *)[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL];
    NSString *moviePath = [videoUrl path];

    if ( UIVideoAtPathIsCompatibleWithSavedPhotosAlbum(moviePath) ) {

        ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

        [assetLibrary assetForURL:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] resultBlock:^(ALAsset *asset) {

            CLLocation *location = [asset valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyLocation];
            NSLog(@"Location Meta: %@", location);

        } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Video Date Error: %@", error);
        }];

    }

}
```

Comment: How to achieve it through the PHAsset in swift

Answer (score 0):

Get all videos Gelocation

```
 PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization { (status) -> Void in
        let videosOption = PHFetchOptions()
        videosOption.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "mediaType = %d", PHAssetMediaType.video.rawValue)
        videosOption.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
        let allVids = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: videosOption)
        for index in 0..<allVids.count {
            //print Location here
            print(allVids[index].location as Any)
        }

    }
```

Comment: I want to get only the location of the chosen video. How can i get the current choosed index and get that respective asset location?